# C# File.Delete doesn't not work

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I am trying to delete some files in a directory from a separate thread, but sometimes the delete doesn't work.

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
foreach (FileInfo fileName in fileNames)
{
    string destinationFilename = cncDestinationDirectory + @"\" + dirInfo.Name + @"\" + fileName.Name;
    if (File.Exists(destinationFilename))
        File.Delete(destinationFilename);

    File.Move(fileName.FullName, destinationFilename);
}
```

My goal is to move some files in a directory but, as I know the `File.Move` doesn't work if the destination file already exists. So, I check if the file exists and if it is true, I delete this file, then move to the original.

The `File.Delete` also cause a prematurely exit from the function.
The current directory is not the same folder as the executable is running because I set previously it into another folder.

How can I avoid this error? And still move the files in the destination directory?

Comment: "prematurely exit"? What does that mean? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: I don't see a question...

Comment: You need to decide how to handle error cases like you suggest in your question.   It's entirely possible that between checking the file exists and then deleting it, that the file has been opened by another process.  You can catch an exception around the File.Delete and then not move the origin file if it throws, but you will end up with files that haven't moved.  There's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @DavidG it means that when it execute the File.Delete, it exits from the function and doesn't execute any other instructions.

Comment: @Neil the destination file aren't being used from another process. They are simple text files and in my application I never open it or do some operations (except for the delete).

As I know the File.Delete doesn' t threw any exceptions. Am I right?

Comment: That's just not possible without throwing an exception. You may be silently swallowing it in whatever method is calling this though - don't ever do that.

Comment: Potentially, your antivirus will try and access/lock the file you are trying to move at the exact moment you do it.

Comment: I agree with @DavidG if there is no UI in this section of the program, then you should consider returning a collection of files that couldn't be moved to the calling function.  Then at least this can be communicated with the user (either by a message box, or some other indication).

Comment: Question you are adding cncDestinationDirectory  + the current directory.... are you sure this arrives at a valid path? can you give an example

Comment: I wonder if this statement is actually true, have you checked it "The current directory is not the same folder as the executable is running because I set previously it into another folder". I would set a breakpoint and double check the paths.

Comment: I know that the path is valid, because the `File.Exists` retrieve true. So the path is correct and I have check more that one time to before ask the question.

Basically, my program needs to do some operation in background and send some data to a machine.
The main program creates the cnc files in a specific folder, let's say C:\temp\CNC. Inside this folder, for each sets of files the main program creates a subfolder like Job1. I have to get those files, send it to the machine and then move those files in another directory.

Comment: So, when this code is executed we have: 
CurrentDirectory = C:\temp\cnc\Job1;
CncDestinationDirectory = C:\temp\JobDone;
destinationDirectory=CncDestinationDirectory + Job1 + filename

Comment: Then doesnt that end up with c:\temp\jobdone\c:\temp\cnc\job1\somefilehere ?

Comment: dirInfo.Name retrieves the name of the folder, not the complete path, and this is the same as fileName.Name.

Comment: Why these downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem there is that the access to the file is denied because of the read only attribute of the file.

So, I set all my files attributes as normal as the follow:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
foreach (FileInfo fileName in fileNames)
{
    if (fileName.Extension == ".iso")
        return;

    string destinationFilename = cncDestinationDirectory + @"\" + dirInfo.Name + @"\" + fileName.Name;
    fileName.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
    if (File.Exists(destinationFilename))
    {
        File.SetAttributes(destinationFilename, FileAttributes.Normal);
        File.Delete(destinationFilename);
    }

    File.Move(fileName.FullName, destinationFilename);
}
```

Comment: How do you solve this problem?  Do you detect the file is R/O and set the attributes accordingly, or skip them, or what?

Comment: I set all the files attribute as Normal with `File.SetAttributes(destinationFilename, FileAttributes.Normal);`
Because those files don't need to have any special attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide how to handle error cases like you suggest in your question. It's entirely possible that between checking the file exists and then deleting it, that the file has been opened by another process. You can catch an exception around the File.Delete and then not move the origin file if it throws, but you will end up with files that haven't moved. There's nothing you can do about it.

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
foreach (FileInfo fileName in fileNames)
{
    string destinationFilename = cncDestinationDirectory + @"\" + dirInfo.Name + @"\" + fileName.Name;
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(destinationFilename))
            File.Delete(destinationFilename);

        File.Move(fileName.FullName, destinationFilename);
    }
    catch(IOException exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Can't move file { filename.FullName}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented the try-catch statement, but it doesn't get any exceptions

Comment: Instead of IOException I have used the Exception. It retrieves an Access Denied. 
But there are no antivirus or any other processes that block the files.

Comment: @KingOfMazes the file may be read only, try setting the file attributes to normal like so File.SetAttributes(fileName, FileAttributes.Normal);

Comment: @jasondinAlt yes, it was that. I have already find the problem. Thank you.